# Shortcut to select uneditable text in Chrome page

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Lets say I have a wikipedia page open within chrome and I want to select certain parts of texts without using my mouse, how would I do that? Basically as if I selected text with my mouse with left click to select text parts, I want to do that with my keyboard.

I googled through windows and chrome shortcuts but couldnt find anything useful. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caret browsing gives you a cursor that moves within the webpage, so if you enable this feature you'll be able to select text with the cursor and shift keys. Firefox supports this feature natively, and Chrome can gain this functionality through an extension such as [Caret Browsing](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caret-browsing/fklpgenihifpccgiifchnihilipmbffg?hl=en-US)